# OpenGL: While drawing a polygon, what if the first vertex is outside of the screen space (Triangle fans)

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I'm following *Computer Graphics Through OpenGL, 2nd Edition* by Sumanta Guha second edition, and in the page 35, it says that

> Raising the first vertex of (the original) square.cpp from `glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 0.0)` to `glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 1.5)` causes the square – actually, the new figure which is not a square any more – to be clipped. If, instead, the second vertex is raised from `glVertex3f(80.0, 20.0, 0.0)` to `glVertex3f(80.0, 20.0, 1.5)`, then the figure is clipped too, but very differently from when the first vertex is raised. Why? Should not the results be similar by symmetry?
>
> Hint: OpenGL draws polygons after triangulating them as so-called triangle fans with the first vertex of the polygon the center of the fan. For example, the fan in Figure 2.16 consists of three triangles around vertex v0.

where the corresponding code looks like

```
  glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(80.0, 20.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(80.0, 80.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(20.0, 80.0, 0.0);
```

if I set only the z-axis of the first vertex to 1.5f, I get such an output,

[image]

And if I set only the z-axis of the second vertex to 1.5f, I get the following output

[image]

In the latter case, I can understand why I get that output because of the clipping, but I don't understand why I get that output in the former case.

Answer (score 5):

You are drawing two triangles: A,B,C and A,C,D.

If you change one `z` of one of the vertices, both triangles will not lie in the same plane any more.

In the first case, you change A which affects both trianges. In the second case, you are changing B which will affect only the second triangle.

Be warned that the code you are using is horribly outdated, and *will not work* in a modern core profile of OpenGL, where "modern" means: since a *decade*.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the author uses this just for the first chapter.